# Facebook session is expired even though I am logged in to facebook

Tags: session, facebook, expired-sessions

I am using facebooker with rails and when I log in via facebook connect, for a new user registration ,I get a session expired when I retrieve details like first_name etc..
Note that when I browse to facebook.com I am logged in..But it seems like that my app has an old session. How do I fix this?

Comment: Note that,the only way to fix this is to go ahead and delete the cookies for my website..

Answer (score 0):

It's not an expired session (obviously), you are using a wrong App ID or App Secret, or both. Or your application is not even registered yet?